# Svelte make {:then} value of {#await} statement reactive

Tags: request, svelte

I have to make an api call and then display the data (an array). I want to sort the array, but the displayed data is not updated. I suppose this is because my `data` is not a reactive variable? How can I make my `each` loop rerun when `data` changes?

My code (simplified):

```
{#await promise} // api call
    <p>Loading</p>
{:then data}
    <button on:click={() => data.sort()}>sort data</button> // does not work
    {#each data as student}
        <p>{student.firstname}</p>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a reactive variable. The presence of a promise is unrelated to the issue: this occurs even if `data` is a normal variable. The issue is that Svelte doesn't properly pick up that a change occurred to `data` when you click the button. You can force Svelte to pick up the changes by explictly assigning to `data`.

The other issue is that you can't sort objects without providing a custom sort function to sort based on a key of the object. `.sort((a, b) => a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname))` sorts based on the `firstname` property of the objects.

Putting that together gives us:

```html
<button on:click={() => data = data.sort((a, b) => a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname))}>sort data</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't write the sorting function because I thought it irrelevant to the question.